# MySQL database schema migration

Tags: mysql, database, migration

I am looking for a solution for schema migration between two different mysql database , just wondering if there is a ready product for it.

scenario:

```
Source Database:

tbl **city** :
  fields: 
      id (int)
      name (varchar)
      country (varchar)

Destination Database

tbl **city** : 
  fields  
      id (int)
      name (varchar) 
      country_id (int)

tbl **country** :
      id (int)
      name (varchar)
```

It will get data from source database and will split country (varchar) and while importing to destination database it will populate country table from source.city.country field.

Its just example , i am looking for a solution like scriptable database migration.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this: http://bitbucket.org/idler/mmp

Comment: There isnt any documentation but as far i understand , it just exporting. i prefer something more visual.

Answer (score 0):

I built a migrations tool that would work perfectly for what you need:

http://andrefigueira.github.io/Schematic/

It will map existing databases into the configuration files (schema files) and then can be used for future modifications, and these schema files are designed to be committed to your VCS and It's very simple to use.